# How to use pointers for relations using parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have created an app that allows users to make post and others can comment. In MainActivity, when a user clicks on a post, it takes the user to a CommentActivity.

The object id of the post is retrieved:

```
post_id = intent.getStringExtra("post_id");
```

The post with the comment:

```
Comments comments = new Comments();
comments.put("parent",ParseObject.createWithoutData("post",post_id));
```

However, when querying the comment nothing appears:

```
ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Comments>factory= new ParseObjectAdapter.QueryFactory<Comments>(){
    ParseQuery<Comments>query =Comments.getquery();
    query.whereEqualTo("parent",post_id);
    query.include ("user");
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt"); 
    return query;
}};
```

How do I query objects that are links using pointers?

Comment: You do know that parse is getting shut down in January and will stop working?

Comment: Please move your project to Firebase, It´s own by google, therefore it will have support, If you have questions about firebase just let me know.

Comment: in order to use "query.include ("user")"  you need to have corresponding field/type in "Comments". So, i Comments.user is of type Pointer<_User>  then the query result will inline the parse.user record pointed to by Comments.user.. PS to avoid semantic confuse, i would change Comments.user to "Comments.ptrUsr" or something ....

Comment: I think that the problem you are having is that you use `whereEqualTo("parent", post_id)` to match the post.  But "parent" is a pointer, not an int.  So you should try something like: `whereEqualTo("parent", (new Post().set('id', post_id))` not sure the exact way to do with the java sdk, but the key is to use an object with the id set, not just the id.

Comment: @TheAndroidDev parse.com is shutting down, parse-server is alive and well.

Answer (score -1):

You should not use pointer for one-many relationship. Instead, use **Relation**.

[Docs for Parse relation](https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/android/guide/#relations)

[Parse Relation tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/one-to-many-relationships--2)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The link to your given answer is broken.